# Solving a DE Similar to Logistic Function

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I am having some problems involving the following separable differential equation:

$$\frac{dP}{dt} = cP\ln\left(\frac{k}{P}\right)$$

I am asked to make the substitution $z(t) = P(t)/k$ and write the differential equation for $z(t)$ and then find the general solution.

So far I have tried separating the equation and then integrating both sides but I am not too sure if I am even doing that correctly as I have not been able to substitute in the expression for $z(t)$ they have given me.

In classes we have gone through the full derivation for the logistic equation and have researched online but have not really been able to clear my confusion.

Thanks for reading and sorry for posting again so soon,

Michael

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Of course you can change $z=\frac{P}{k}$, but then changes all the differential equation, getting $k\frac{dz}{dt}=czk\ln(z)$

Comment: Thanks I have tried making that substitution however I'm not sure what I keep doing because I managed to get integral( dz/z*ln(z)) = integral(c dt) which seems a little off but I'll keep playing around with that idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the right track getting the $ \int{\frac{dz}{z \ln z}} $

You just need to actually evaluate that by letting $ y = \ln(z) $, so $ dy = \frac{1}{z} dz $

For the full solution:

Let $ z(t) = \frac{P(t)}{k} $, we get $ \frac{dz}{dt} = k\frac{dP}{dt} $

Substitute it all back to the equation, we get

$ \frac{dP}{dt} = cP\ln(\frac{k}{P}) $

$ k\frac{dP}{dt} = ckP\ln(\frac{k}{P}) $

$ \frac{dz}{dt} = ck^2z\ln(\frac{1}{z}) $

$ \frac{dz}{dt} = -ck^2z\ln(z) $

$ \int{\frac{dz}{z\ln(z)}} = \int {-ck^2dt} $

$ \int{\frac{dy}{y}} = \int {-ck^2dt} $

$ \ln y = -ck^2t + C $

$ \ln (\ln z) = -ck^2t + C $

$ (\ln z) = e^{-ck^2t + C} $

$ z = e^{e^{-ck^2t + C}} $

$ p = ke^{e^{-ck^2t + C}} $

I checked that is an correct answer when $ c = k = 1 $ , $ C = 0 $

Comment: Thank you I see understand now. Not only was I unsure with my steps so far I had also incorrectly manipulated the right hand side of the equation. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

Starting from $$P' = cP\ln\left(\frac{k}{P}\right)$$ you can start using $$P=k e^{-z}\qquad P'=-kz'e^{-z}$$ to get rid of the logarithm. Doing so, the differential equation becomes, after factoring and simplification, $$c z+z'=0\implies z=C_1 e^{-c t}$$ Back to $P$ $$P=k e^{-c_1 e^{-c t}}$$